# Why mybatis default ExecutorType is Simple not Batch?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Why mybatis default ExecutorType is Simple not Batch ? Batch is more effective than Simple . Why use Simple as default ExecutorType ?

Answer (score 0):

The default executor type is SIMPLE because the SIMPLE executor does nothing special. REUSE executor reuses prepared statements. The BATCH executor reuses statements and batches updates. Other than the SIMPLE executor type both have their different and specific uses which should not be executed by default.

Comment: for reference you can visit: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html